# jQuery: Find object item with same index, and paste one after the other

Tags: jquery, object, each

I've two div with serveral ul lists:

```html
<div class="pt-schedual-1">
  <ul id="cell_1"><li>Cell 1</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_2"><li>Cell 2</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_3"><li>Cell 3</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="pt-schedual-2">
  <ul id="cell_4"><li>Cell 4</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_5"><li>Cell 5</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_6"><li>Cell 6</li></ul>
</div>
```

which I want to:

1. put them into two jquery objects
2. find items with same index, and put one after another

```js
$('.pt-schedual-2').load(function () {
  var $obj1 = $('.pt-schedual-1').find('ul');
  var $obj2 = $('.pt-schedual-2').find('ul');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pt-schedual-1">
  <ul id="cell_1"><li>Cell 1</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_4"><li>Cell 4</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_2"><li>Cell 2</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_5"><li>Cell 5</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_3"><li>Cell 3</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_6"><li>Cell 6</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="pt-schedual-2">
  <ul id="cell_4"><li>Cell 4</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_5"><li>Cell 5</li></ul>
  <ul id="cell_6"><li>Cell 6</li></ul>
</div>
```

I've tried using each() with object index.. but not work at all. 
Need a liitle hint here, thank you.

Comment: So the 2 lists should remain separate? Do you want these `ul`'s in an object or array? And you want to order each list by it's `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
var $obj1 = $('.pt-schedual-1').find('ul');
var $obj2 = $('.pt-schedual-2').find('ul');

$obj2.clone().each(function(i) {
   $(this).insertAfter( $obj1.get(i) );
});
```